# Storing live video on Azure Media Services

Tags: azure, video-streaming, azure-storage, azure-media-services

I have one interesting scenario using Windows Azure to store video directly from IP cameras.

I know Azure Media Services is amazing to video streaming, but I do not know if it  is possible to use Media services to store video from IP secure cameras.

Have someone here experience with that?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible if your camera or your streaming software supports RTMP or Fragmented MP4 as streaming protocol.

#### How to get things ready:

As you can see in the image below, the entity that stores a live streaming is "Program".

[image]

### Common live streaming scenario

The following steps describe tasks involved in creating common live streaming applications.

1. Connect a video camera to a computer. Launch and configure an on-premises live encoder that outputs a multi-bitrate RTMP or Fragmented MP4 (Smooth Streaming) stream. (Like [WireCast](http://telestream.net/wirecast/overview.htm?__c=1)) *This step could also be performed after you create your Channel.*
2. Create and start a Channel.
3. Retrieve the Channel ingest URL. The ingest URL is used by the live encoder to send the stream to the Channel.
4. Retrieve the Channel preview URL. Use this URL to verify that your channel is properly receiving the live stream.
5. Create a program. When using the Azure Management Portal, creating a program also creates an asset. When using .NET SDK or REST you need to create an asset and specify to use this asset when creating a Program.
6. Publish the asset associated with the program. Make sure to have at least one streaming reserved unit on the streaming endpoint from which you want to stream content.
7. Start the program when you are ready to start streaming and archiving. Optionally, the live encoder can be signaled to start an advertisement. The advertisement is inserted in the output stream.
8. Stop the program whenever you want to stop streaming and archiving the event.
9. Delete the Program (and optionally delete the asset).

All these task can be made by using the [Azure Management Portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com), [.NET SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-media-services), [Java SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java), Azure Media Services REST API, etc.

More details [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-manage-channels-overview/)